html2canvas: dataURL is always empty (only) on mobile devices
Here is my code:
const element = document.querySelector("#copycontent");
const canvas = await html2canvas(element, { logging: true });
const imgURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
const pdf = new jsPDF();
pdf.addImage(imgURL, 'PNG', 0, 0, 170, 53.5);
pdf.save('information.pdf');

This code works like a charm in all browsers on desktop. As far as I switch to a mobile device (iphone, android, ipad etc.) it gives me the following error: Supplied Data is not a valid base64-String jsPDF.convertStringToImageData
What i've found out, the error is correct, because imgURL is only data:,. The element is found correctly by the code (also on my phone), but if the function html2canvas will be executed, is canvas an empty canvas - and the result is that imgURL = data:,.
Can anybody help me with this issue?
Thanks! :)

Repository link of html2canvas: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL#return_value: "If the height or width of the canvas is 0 or larger than the maximum canvas size, the string "data:," is returned." - suppose that could have something to do with your problem? Does your #copycontent element actually have dimensions on mobile?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#maximum_canvas_size: "While in most cases the maximum dimensions exceed 10,000 x 10,000 pixels, notably iOS devices limit the canvas size to only 4,096 x 4,096 pixels." - or does your #copycontent maybe exceed those dimensions (in either direction)?
